# Why can't I import a var from php to js using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to work with ajax, but I'm stuck, because I tried various things to import a var from a php file to js. What am I supposed to write after the `success: function()` to import `$rowcount` to js? I know that there are already some questions and answers on the site, but none of those seems to work...

Here's the php code:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pw = "";

$dbName = "mathgame";
$tblName = "fragen";
// mit mysql db verbinden

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $dbName);
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die ("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

// Datenanfrage an db

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select id from $tblName where Kategorie='Kategorie1'");
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
json_encode($rowcount);
?>
```

And the js code:

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'Kategorie1.php',           //the script to call to get data
    data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
    //for example "id=5&parent=6"
    dataType: 'json',                //data format
    success: function(){
    }
})
```

Comment: how your php response look like?

Comment: The success callback takes one parameter, you work with it to get your data from PHP into your JS code

Answer (score 0):

json_encode() returns a string but your code does nothing with the value. All you need to do is write the return value to stdout. One way to do that is:

```
echo json_encode($rowcount);
```

Comment: oh yeah, missed that thanks..
But I still dont know what to add after success: function(){

Comment: @loelu: the `success` function gets passed the response as first argument. Add a parameter to the function and put the code that wants to do something with the response in the function. Look at the jQuery documentation, it has examples.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to take in the data that is returned from your PHP script.

Add the data after `success: function(` for you to manipulate and use the return data.

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'Kategorie1.php',           //the script to call to get data
    data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
    //for example "id=5&parent=6"
    dataType: 'json',                //data format
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); // outputs the json data into your console
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.getJSON("Kategorie1.php", function (data) {
    var nrFragen = JSON.parse(data);
```

That's the js code, which worked for me, and of course at the end of the php code there should be : `echo json_encode($rowcount);`